# Zeitwerk fails in production loading custom SimpleNavigation renderer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

Getting ready for Rails 7 by shifting to Zeitwerk autoloader (Rails 6.1.4.4 on Ruby 2.7.5). Turned off the `config.autoloader = :classic` line in application.rb. App is loading 6.1 defaults.

Dev mode runs fine, but production fails on boot (also fails locally in production mode):

```
pid=4 tid=2l2g WARN: Zeitwerk::NameError: expected file /app/app/navigation_renderers/public_issue_renderer.rb to define constant PublicIssueRenderer, but didn't
pid=4 tid=2l2g WARN: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded'
```

(This is on Heroku-20 in a staging environment).

That file does define that as a class, however.:

```
module SimpleNavigation
  module Renderer
    class PublicIssueRenderer < SimpleNavigation::Renderer::Base
      [functions removed for brevity]
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure why the double `/app/app` exists, as the directory is simply in app along with everything else:

[image: screen shot of file directory from rails app in question]

Answer (score 1):

Since `app/navigation_renderers` belongs to the autoload paths, the file

```
app/navigation_renderers/public_issue_renderer.rb
```

should define `PublicIssueRenderer` at the top-level.

This is the same rule that says that `app/models/user.rb` has to define exactly `User`, not `SimpleNavigation::Renderer::User`.

See?

Also, it is really, really strange that development mode worked in `classic` with that file. Because that file does not follow `classic` expectations either, they are the same expectations.

Maybe the application is configuring or doing something funky?

Does `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` pass? You can run it before deploying. And also you can eager load in CI, which is a good idea (see [these docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-eager-loading)).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get past this was to put these two lines at the top of the file:

```
class PublicIssueRenderer
end
```

and then continue with the module as shown above. Feels wrong, but it passes Zeitwerk and still works.